# Cant delete void pointer from vector in c++

Tags: c++, pointers, vector, void

hi everybody im trying to delete void pointer from vector, the program crash in the delete.
thank you very much!

```
template <class T> class tArray_t : public vpArr_t {
  virtual ~tArray_t() {

   for (vector<void*>::iterator it = array.begin() ; it != array.end(); )
   {
          vector<void*>::iterator nextElement = it+1;
          delete *it; // here is the crash
          it = nextElement; 
   }
```

};

Comment: You are not removing the pointer from the vector, but deleting the memory occupied by the pointer.

Comment: You should increment `it` in the `for()` statement, not in the loop body.

Comment: Why do you need `nextElement`? Why not just `it = it + 1;` or `it++;`?

Comment: If it's crashing on the `delete` operation, it means you have an invalid pointer in the vector; or at least a pointer that wasn't allocated with `new`.

Comment: C++ standard section 5.3.5/3 : `[...] an object cannot be deleted using a pointer of type void* because there are no objects of type void.`

Comment: I'm wondering why these are void pointers in the first place. Judging by the class name, why not just a template?

Comment: @user3570497 how are you making sure that it+1 is a valid pointed location and its not past the last element i.e. the end()?

Comment: @Nik Because you can't enter the loop body if `it` equals `end()`.

Comment: @Chnossos what if it==(lastElement) and then you do "it+1", are you not crossing the last element here? and after that trying to delete tht location which was not assigned via the code or may belong to some other code.

Comment: @Nik He's actually deleting `it`, not `nextElement` so if it reached that point everything is good with this. Standard containers ensure that `end()` is always **past** the last element.

Comment: @Nik: Yes, one-past-the-last-element is allowed, and is, in fact, where the `end` iterator points.

Comment: @Chnossos understood :)

Comment: If you're doing what I think you're *trying*, you may eventually find [this interesting](https://ideone.com/evzE76). It blows most people away when they see it.

Comment: @WhozCraig: huh, I hadn't realized `shared_ptr`s could be cast to `shared_ptr<void>`.  Neat trick.  `boost::any` is still preferred IMO.

Answer (score 9):

Deleting `void` pointers is **undefined**. You are getting exactly what you have asked for.

Use `vector<T*>` instead of `vector<void*>`. If you e.g. have `vector<void*>` inherited from your base class, you have to cast the pointer to `T*` before deleting it.

```
delete static_cast<T*>(*it);
```

You may also want to save you some work and use `boost::ptr_vector`.

Comment: Is it? Even if I called `operator new(42)`? Please add a quote.

Comment: @user3570497: I see no templates in your code, so my only suggestion is to use `std::unique_ptr` or `boost::variant` or `boost::any`, in that order.

Comment: @Deduplicator C++ standard section 5.3.5/3 : _[...] an object cannot be deleted using a pointer of type `void*` because there are no objects of type `void`._ And _if the dynamic type of the object to be deleted differs from its static type, **the behavior is undefined**._ (emphasis mine)

Comment: I think it is only undefined behavior if it points to an object with a destructor. See footnote 81 of 5.3.5.1 "This implies that an object cannot be deleted using a pointer of type void* because void is not an object type".

Comment: @Deduplicator "if the static type of the object to be deleted is different from its dynamic type, the static type shall be a base class of the dynamic type of the object to be deleted and the static type shall have a virtual destructor or the behavior is undefined." (5.3.5/3) Since this cannot possibly hold for `void*`, it's always undefined. FWIW GCC warns: `warning: deleting ‘void*’ is undefined [enabled by default]`.

Comment: I also just noticed: "If the object being deleted has incomplete class type at the point of deletion and the complete class has a non-trivial destructor or a deallocation function, the behavior is undefined."  also, "Incompletely defined object types and the void types are incomplete types"

Comment: template <class T> class tArray_t : public vpArr_t {
virtual ~tArray_t() {

   for (vector<void*>::iterator it = array.begin() ; it != array.end(); )
   {
          vector<void*>::iterator nextElement = it+1;
          delete *it; // here is the crash
          it = nextElement; 
   }
};

Comment: @Jens It says "This implies that an object cannot be deleted using a pointer of type void\*". It does not say "This implies that an object *with a destructor* cannot be deleted using a pointer of type void\*" or anything like that. Read what's written.

Comment: @user3570497 Don't post clarifications in comments, especially ones that contain code. Edit your question and insert them there.

Comment: I think there is some confusion due to the use of the word "object" in the quoted section of the spec. To a casual reader, that seems to imply "object" in the C++ sense; i.e. an instance of a class. I don't think that is the case, though.

Comment: @dlf That is exactly how I read it, thinking that object means something of class type. That distinction is quite common, so I assumed it there too. But reading the beginning of the standard, it turns out that integral types are arithmetic types which are POD-types which are possible object types. Learnt something new today.

Comment: @dlf Object in the C++ sense is *a region of storage* (1.8), not an instance of a class. That would be an object in the OO sense. C++ is not exclusively an OO language.

Comment: thank you all for trying to help me, i try to do the static_cast
but its not work. i have to use with void*. in the vector there are pointer to int

Comment: @n.m. Right you are. I'd say it's a pedantic distinction, but where else to be pedantic if not in a discussion of the specification of a programming language? :D

Comment: "i try to do the static_cast but its not work." Define "not work". "i have to use with `void*`". You can try but it won't work.

Comment: thank you all, i looked at the code and you have right, i tried to delete unallocated pointer.. i just use the clear function of vector. thank you again!

Answer (score 1):

Compiler know how many bytes to be deleted with a typed pointer. Think of it this way, a void * pointer doesn't have any information about the memory it pointing to, nobody knows how to delete a pointer like this. To the minimum, you don't know what size needs to be deleted, and no information about which destructor to call.

```
Class A;
A * p = new A();
delete p;
```

When delete p is executed, compiler knows A destrcutor needs to be called, and the size of memory needs to be cleaned up is sizeof(A). A void * pointer is missing all this information.

Comment: That's not actually true. The runtime implementation keeps the size information in a block at that address. The real reason he can't do it is because he used the wrong form of `delete`.